# Flutter how to show AlertDialog on particular page only

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am building a chess clock in flutter. when i change clocks time duration in settings page i want to ask the user for confirmation using alert dialog. I want the alert dialog to only appear in homepage right now it appears immediately after I change duration in settings page.

I am using provider to manage state when I change duration I change a bool value to true. then in the home page I check if the bool value is true then run the alert dialog code. I tried putting dialog code in `future delay.Zero` but it did not work.

right now home page rebuilds immediatly after i change settings and alert dialog pops up.

my code:

```dart
// home page code
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin, WidgetsBindingObserver {

// code for initstate and logic

late AnimationController _whiteControl;
  late AnimationController _blackControl;

  int whiteTime = 1;
  int blackTime = 1;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);

    _whiteControl = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: whiteTime * 60),
    );

    _blackControl = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: blackTime * 60),
    );

@override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    _whiteControl.dispose();
    _blackControl.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var gameState = Provider.of<GameState>(context, listen: false);
    final ChoiceDialog resetChoice = ChoiceDialog(
      buttonOkOnPressed: () {
        _blackControl.reset();
        _whiteControl.reset();
        gameState.isgameChanged = false;
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      buttonCancelOnPressed: () {
        gameState.isgameChanged = false;
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );

    if (gameState.isGameStarted && gameState.isgameChanged) {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        print(' Game Changed ');
        resetChoice.show(context);
      });
    }
 print(' Rebuilding Home Page ---');
    return Scaffold();
//reset of homepage code
```

Settings Page Code:

```dart
class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Settings'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: gamesList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Consumer<GameState>(
                    builder: (context, _gameState, child) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          _gameState.changeGame(gamesList[index]);
                        },
                        child: Container(),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Provider State Logic:

```dart
class Game {
  final String name;
  final int whiteTime;
  final int blackTime;

  Game({
    required this.name,
    required this.whiteTime,
    required this.blackTime,
  });
}

class GameState with ChangeNotifier {
  bool turnWhite = false;
  bool turnBlack = false;
  bool isgameChanged = false;
  bool isClocksFinished = false;
  bool isPaused = false;
  bool isGameStarted = false;
  bool resetGame = false;

  int white = 0;
  int black = 0;

  Game _currentGame = gamesList[0];

  Game get currentGame => _currentGame;

  bool get isWhiteTurn => turnWhite;

  void resetGameClocks() {
    resetGame = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setTurnWhite() {
    turnWhite = true;
    turnBlack = false;
    isGameStarted = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setTurnBlack() {
    turnWhite = false;
    turnBlack = true;
    isGameStarted = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void changeGame(Game game) {
    _currentGame = game;
    isgameChanged = true;
    white = game.whiteTime;
    black = game.blackTime;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

project repository: https://github.dev/tonydavidx/chess-clock-app/tree/dev

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code you did a blunder in a very initial point/starting point of the Homepage screen kindly avoid this

never ever initialize or put your code before returning in build function of widgets if you really need some logic or code to be executed in the beginning then put it inside an `initstate()` or inside your provider constructor and handle it properly.

this is the root cause of the problem which you are facing.

Comment: I initialized the animation controllers in the `initstate` when i want to reset the durations i check if the certain condition true every time page builds and run the reset code alert dialog.  
please check my project repo: https://github.dev/tonydavidx/chess-clock-app/tree/dev

Comment: put the reset code logic inside a `initstate` and manage the state properly all the issue is with your state management technique or in more short state is leaking ;)